# much - very much, many - very many?

Tags: determiners, emphasis

In case of uncountables, the large amount expressed by `much` like in

> much water, much money, much sand

can be increased by prepending `very` like in

> very much water, very much money, very much sand

But in case of countables, the large amount expressed by `many` like in

> many trees, many people, many children

can **not** be increased by prepending `very`? So, the following is wrong?

> very many trees, very many people, very many children

Is there a comprehensible explanation for this difference?

And what is/are the correct expression(s) to increase `many`?

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken. It is correct to use **very** to increase **many**. To me it sounds simply a little redundant and begs the inclusion of more specific information since, as you pointed out, **many** is used for countables.

For example, the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> There are **very many** trees in the park.

However, in conversation I would then reply:

> How **many** trees are there?

Or perhaps I would inquire as to the variety of the trees.

One can also use **great** to increase **many**:

> There are **a great many** trees in the park.

Note the use of the indefinite article "**a**" with **great many**.